# How to format a date to following format day.month.year?

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat

I need to format a date to following format: `10.12.2014` and I am using the following code but it returns following error

```
   Messages:    
   Unparseable date: "2014-12-10"
```

**Code**

```
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
   Date date = formatter.parse(param.getFromDate());
   String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
```

Comment: shouldnt it be yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: look here [kotlin Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77656309/11370863) and support Lower API level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your date format, you are parsing `yyyy-MM-dd` and providing format as `yyyy.MMMM.dd`:-

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 Date date = formatter.parse(param.getFromDate());
 String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
```

Edit:- you updated format input to `dd.mm.yyyy` , which again is wrong, and above solution is valid in this case too.

Also you want the date output as `10.12.2014`, which you can do by creating new formatter and parsing the date to string using it:-

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
String formattedDate2 = formatter.format(date); //
```

Comment: If your input is in format for example `2014-12-10`,then you should   provide format as `yyyy-MM-dd` , if your input is `2014.12.10` format will be `yyyy.MM.dd`, note the capital `MM` for month , `mm` is for minutes

Comment: the required output is 10.12.2014 not 2014.12.10

Answer (score 5):

`Unparseable date` means your input dateString value is not in the same format as expected.
*For example*, if your dateString is 2014-12-10 (`yyyy-MM-dd`) , if you try to format it to `dd-MM-yyyy`, then this exception will occur.

The following code will help you.!

```
// Existing date is in this format : "2014-12-10"
SimpleDateFormat formatFrom = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

// Required date is in this format : 10.12.2014
SimpleDateFormat formatTo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

// Convert the String  param.getFromDate()==>2014-12-10 to a Date
Date date = formatFrom .parse(param.getFromDate());

// Convert Date to String 10.12.2014
String formattedDate = formatTo .format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out: [Java Docs for SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

contains all the pattern letters for date and time, helped me a lot when i was looking onto how to implement date and time in my app.

Comment: Your answer is likely to get downvoted. Avoid providing link based answers. Also the answer is not specific to user's problem. Otherwise every java problem could be answered by providing link to java docs :)